# GST number validation in php

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to implement GST validation in php.

```
if(!preg_match("/^([0-5]){2}([a-zA-Z]){5}([0-9]){4}([a-zA-Z]){1}([a-zA-Z0-9]){1}([a-zA-Z]){1}([0-9]){1}?$/", $testcase)) {
        $flag = "Invalid GST number ";
        return $flag;
    }
```

1st 2 digits are state code which will be between 01 to 35, but my code will accept 01 to 55 which is wrong. Any way to validate it upto 35 only.

Answer (score 5):

You need to break you number range into the actual digits.

The following will work

```
if(!preg_match("/^(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-5])([a-zA-Z]){5}([0-9]){4}([a-zA-Z]){1}([a-zA-Z0-9]){1}([a-zA-Z]){1}([0-9]){1}?$/", $testcase)) {
    $flag = "Invalid GST number ";
    return $flag;
}
```

The number regex works as follows, we split out the first 2 digit validation into 3 scenarios.We use the or operator **|** to split out into the scenarios.

```
(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-5])
```

- The 2 digits start with zero

  - The second digit can only be between 1 and 9
  - Allows: 01-09
- The 2 digits start with a 1 or 2

  - Allow the second degit to be 0-9
  - Allows 10-29
- The 2 digits start with a 3

  - Allows the second digit to be 0-5
  - Allows 30-35

Hope this helps

Comment: glad its working for you! after test if its all working for you please mark as the answer, thanks again!

Comment: this completely failed after I entered my gstin for testing and 3 other gstin.

Comment: this regex failed for 29ALLPG8905G1ZT

Answer (score 1):

i think you should start the regex with:

`/^([0-2][0-9])|(3[0-5])`

edit: a flaw: this also allows 00

Comment: Thanks buddy, your answer gave me an idea. This will also remove your flaw of 00

preg_match("/^([0-3]){1}([1-5]){1}([a-zA-Z]){5}([0-9]){4}([a-zA-Z]){1}([a-zA-Z0-9]){1}([a-zA-Z]){1}([0-9]){1}?$/", $testcase)
it's workign for me

Comment: you may have to play around with the ( en ) to get it working completely

Comment: is you solution also working when starting 10 or 20? or 26 ?

Comment: This solution will not work for values like 16, 17, 28 20 10 etc. Please check my answers. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
    $gst="11ABCD2222E1EF";  
    if (!preg_match("/^([0-9]){2}([A-Za-z]){5}([0-9]){4}([A-Za-z]){1}([0-9]{1})([A-Za-z]){2}?$/", $pan)) { //GSTN validation
        echo"Invalid GSTN";
    }
    else{
        echo"Valid GSTN";
    }
?>
```

This code will work fine

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!preg_match("/^([0-9]){2}([a-zA-Z]){5}([0-9]){4}([a-zA-Z]){1}([a-zA-Z0-9]){3}$/", $gst_no)) { $gst_invalid=yes; }
```